# conditional mongodb view based on queried value

Tags: mongodb, conditional-statements

I'm not sure this is possible, but i'd like to create a single view or at least a single query that looks in different collections based on what's being queried.
for example, if the first character is an "A" look in the "Aresults" collection, if it's a "B" look in the "Bresults" collection, etc.

I could potentially create a "A-Z" collection with just those letters, and do a $lookup from there based on a condition, but i'm not sure how to do that either.

I am aware that i could create a view with a $unionWith having all the "*results" collections, but that seems very inefficient.

Any other ideas? Is there perhaps some type of dynamic query structure within mongodb like in MySQL (couldn't find any)?

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Something like this?

```
const prefix = db.meta_data.findOne({field: condition}).prefix ;
db.createView('view_name', prefix + 'results', [<your aggregation pipeline>]);
```

or this?

```
const pipeline = [];
db.meta_data.find({ field: condition }).forEach(x => {
   pipeline.push({ $unionWith: { coll: prefix + 'results' } });
});
db.collection.aggregate([pipeline]);
```

Comment: if i understood it correctly, that creates a separate view for each results collection, which is not what i am looking for. as in the question, i am looking to create one view which queries different collections based on the input

Comment: You asked how to create a view based on result of a query. That's what it is doing. You may elaborate your requirements. Replacing `db.meta_data.findOne({field: condition})` by `db.meta_data.find({field: condition}).forEach( x => { db.createView(...) })` should be no big deal.

Comment: as in the question "i'd like to create a single view". your solution is to create multiple views. that's unnecessary since i have multiple collections already. there would be no need for any view if that's what i wanted.

Comment: I have really no idea what you are looking for, but I give a last try. Please see my update.

Comment: that isn't a single query, so not as ideal, but that is interesting. in the second example, where do you define "prefix" ? or should it just say "x" ?

Comment: Just a guess, based on the very sparse information in your question.